# jooq 3.12.0 custom data type binding generated code compile errors

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, jooq

I used jooq in 3.7.3 and now I am upgrading to jooq 3.12.0. I am seeing compile errors in my generated code.

With jooq version 3.7.3, using https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/. I can see my custom data binding class being used ("MySqlJsonBinding") in generated code and I do not get compile errors with the generated code.

Part of my jooq.xml:

```
<customTypes>
    <customType>
    <name>JsonElement</name>
    <type>com.google.gson.JsonElement</type>
    <binding>jooq.MySqlJsonBinding</binding>
    </customType>
</customTypes>
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>JsonElement</name>
        <expression>board_data</expression>
        <types>JSON</types>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Generated code: no compile errors

```
public final TableField<UserBoardRecord, JsonElement> BOARD_DATA = createField("board_data", org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("json"), this, "", new MySqlJsonBinding());
```

With jooq version 3.12.0, using https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/ as my example. I am not seeing "MySqlJsonBinding" in generated code, so I am not sure it is being included.

Part of my jooq.xml:

```
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <userType>com.google.gson.JsonElement</userType>
        <binding>com.samplecompany.jooq.MySqlJsonBinding</binding>
        <includeExpression>.*JSON.*</includeExpression>
        <includeTypes>.*</includeTypes>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Generated code: no compile errors, but no MySqlJsonBinding:

```
public final TableField<UserBoardRecord, JSON> BOARD_DATA = createField(DSL.name("board_data"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, this, "");
```

Lastly, I am using 3.12.0, trying to apply the approach I used for 3.7.3. I do get generated code, and it does contain MySqlJsonBinding, but it has compile errors.

Part of my jooq.xml:

```
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <userType>com.google.gson.JsonElement</userType>
        <binding>com.samplecompany.jooq.MySqlJsonBinding</binding>
        <includeExpression>board_data</includeExpression>
        <includeTypes>JSON</includeTypes>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Generated code:

```
public final TableField<UserBoardRecord, JsonElement> BOARD_DATA = createField(DSL.name("board_data"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, this, "", new MySqlJsonBinding());
```

Compile errors below:

```
ERROR:
Error:(81, 72) java: no suitable method found for createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<org.jooq.JSON>,com.samplecompany.domain.data.tables.UserBoard,java.lang.String,com.samplecompany.jooq.MySqlJsonBinding)
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,U
        (argument mismatch; org.jooq.Name cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,U
        (argument mismatch; org.jooq.Name cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,X,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,X,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,X,U>createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,X,U
        (argument mismatch; org.jooq.Name cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,U
        (argument mismatch; com.samplecompany.jooq.MySqlJsonBinding cannot be converted to org.jooq.Converter<T,U>))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
        inferred: java.lang.Object
        equality constraints(s): java.lang.Object,org.jooq.JSON)
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<R,T,X,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,org.jooq.Table<R>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T,X,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Binding<T,U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.jooq.impl.AbstractTable.<T,X,U>createField(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType<T>,java.lang.String,org.jooq.Converter<X,U>,org.jooq.Binding<T,X>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,X,U
        (argument mismatch; com.samplecompany.domain.data.tables.UserBoard cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

jOOQ 3.12 introduced the new [`org.jooq.JSON`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/JSON.html) type, which applies automatically to your generated code. Before, the type could not be mapped, and was thus generated as `SQLDataType.OTHER`, which corresponds to `java.lang.Object`

Your binding was working before, because it was probably a `Binding<Object, YourType>`. You will have to change this binding to `Binding<JSON, YourType>` to fix this.

Comment: Looks like this is now out of date then?
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/

Comment: @w25r: Yes indeed. There's already an issue to update the manual: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9623

Comment: Hi @LukasEder I think I am having a similar Issue, would appreciate if you could take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950491/jooq-upgraded-jooq-now-my-custom-data-type-binding-does-not-work